# С каким Экспортом/Импортом дружит OCfilter

Tags: opencart

Ребят, тут такое дело, нужен импортер/экспортер который бы дружил с OCFilter. Версия Opencart 2.1

Answer (score 1):

CSV Import\Export Pro через стандартные опции атрибуты.

Comment: Я попробовал им, выбрал фильтры и он ничего не выгнулиз